# Create sum of tasks and time spent in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, task, time-tracking

I have a google sheet with two columns with dropdowns, one has a type of task performed, the second has how long it took for the task. I want to create a sum of the number of task types for the day and a sum of the time spent.  The table looks roughly like this:

| Task Description | Task Type | Time Spent |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Task Description | Web Development | 15 Min |
| Task Description | Network Admin | 1.5 Hours |
| Task Description | Helpdesk | 30 Min |
| Task Description | Network Admin | 30 Min |
| Task Description | Helpdesk | 15 Min |

What I want below is something to tell me how much time was spent for each task type, for instance something that would say Web Development 15 Min, Network Admin 2 Hours, Helpdesk 45 Mins so that I can then take the total amount of time spent and break it into a percentage of the time period worked. I'm not very good with Google Sheets and dropdowns so I'm really unfamiliar with working with that kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

*Here's one approach you may test out:*

```js
=let(Λ,map(unique(tocol(B2:B,1)),lambda(Σ,{Σ,sum(ifna(filter(--left(C:C,find(" ",C:C))*if(iferror(search("hour",C:C)),60,1),B:B=Σ)))})),
     hstack(index(Λ,,1),let(Ξ,index(Λ,,2),index(if(Ξ>60,round(Ξ/60,2)&" hour(s)",Ξ&" min")))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution:

```cpp
=MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(B2:B,1)),
   LAMBDA(task,{task,
     REGEXREPLACE(
       TEXT(
         SUM(FILTER(
               1/{24,1440}*REGEXEXTRACT(C2:C,"(?:([\d.]+) Hours?)|(?:([\d.]+) Mins?)"),
               task=B2:B)),
         "h \hour\s m \min\s"),
       " ?\b0 \w+ ?",)}))
```

## Explanation

Let `duration` be a duration in the format `# hours`, `# mins` or `# hours # mins` where `#` represents a number. The following (array)formula converts this human-readable duration to a duration that Google Sheets can understand

```cpp
SUM(1/{24,1440}*REGEXEXTRACT(duration,"(?:([\d.]+) Hours?)|(?:([\d.]+) Mins?)"))
```

If `duration` is an array of durations, the formula converts all of them to a format that Sheets can understand and sums them.

Now let `duration_gs` be a duration in a format that Sheets understands, the following formula converts it to a human-readable duration

```cpp
TEXT(duration_gs,"h \hour\s m \min\s")
```

This process may end up generating something like `0 hours # mins` or `# hours 0 mins`, so we deal with it with the following regex

```cpp
REGEXREPLACE(duration," ?\b0 \w+ ?",)
```